# Why are comments that start with "//!" colored blue in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt-creator, comments

Qt Creator normally colors comments green, but I saw blue colored comments in the Qt Examples, and Qt Creator seems to color every comment that starts with `//!` in blue.

Here's an example screenshot:

[image]

Is this some convention? What does the blue signify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [Doxygen comment](http://www-glast.slac.stanford.edu/software/CodeHowTo_20021202/doxygen/using_doxygen.htm#dcomments).

There are multiple styles:

Qt block comment:

```
/*!
... text ...
*/
```

Qt one-line comment:

```
//! ... one line of text ...
```

JavaDoc block comment:

```
/**
  * ... text ...
*/
```

JavaDoc one-line comment:

```
/// ... one line of text ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Comments that begin with `//!` are the Qt style for code documentation as contrasted with regular comments.  See [the doxygen manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) for details on the structure of it, but basically, these kinds of comments are intended for automatic extraction into documentation about the code.